# Parse geojson files with C

Tags: c, gis, geojson, gdal, grass

I can't find any simple C source file or library to parse geojson files (implementing [rfc7946](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) standard).

Maybe such parsers exist in projects like GRASS or GDAL? But I still have a little trouble navigating the world of C libraries.

Some tracks ?

Comment: You could always write your own parser

Comment: Three doesn't appear to be anything special about the JSON you're referring to.  Why do you need a special parser?

Comment: @h0r53 I'm agree with that, I also ask the question to know if I will reinvent the wheel or not. But it would be cool to do

Comment: @AndrewHenle Some keys are required, case-sentives and other things. I guess JSON parsers don't implement these checks.

Comment: @ce.teuf If GeoJSON is a strict subset of JSON, than any JSON parser can parse it.  You'd only have to add checks for objects outside of the GeoJSON specification.  That's a lot easier than creating a JSON parser from nothing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ok so I'll do it like this. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) is in JSON format, so you can use JSON parsers. There are several out there:

https://github.com/search?l=C&q=json+parser&type=Repositories

You should add checks and other stuff yourself.

If you need a certain representation of data, you can write it yourself. Mapbox wrote a [C++ version of GeoJSON parser](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-cpp) for converting GeoJSON into geometry.hpp representation based on [RapidJSON](https://rapidjson.org/) in less than 1k lines of code.

A [standard-compliant](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=Supporting%20GeoJSON) (RFC 7946) implementation of GeoJSON in C can be found [inside SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/dir?ci=tip&name=src/gaiageo), but may be it's easier for you to use typical JSON parsers instead. You can take a look in [virtualgeojson.c](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/file?name=src/spatialite/virtualgeojson.c&ci=tip) if you want to use this library.

Answer (score 1):

Ho1's answer is perfect if you want to do basic geometry manipulations. For advanced stuff (that you do not want to reinvent), you could consider using [geos](https://github.com/libgeos/geos)'s CAPI.

Note that the CAPI GeoJSON writer is quite new, and the doc not up to date unfortunately. Here's the header file containing those changes: https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/main/capi/geos_c.h.in

Comment: Thank You ! I will practice by trying to implement the restrictions enacted by the standard. But I keep the package you suggest under my elbow.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got started.

I am writing a [small library](https://github.com/ceteuf/geojson-parser) based on [json-parser](https://github.com/json-parser/json-parser) which allows to say whether or not the parsed json is a valid geojson. (according to standard 7946).

This is obviously a first draft, there is still a lot of work.

I am a beginner in C, so if you have any advice or comments I am obviously interested.